# Remote Access MySQL connection error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2003

I am trying to remotely connect to a MySQL server. I have followed advice from (1) and setup a user on the ip address I will be remotely accessing from.

```
user$ mysql -u TestUser -p -h 129.169.66.149
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '129.169.66.149' (60)
```

I have checked and the port (default, 3306) is correct and the ip address is correct. MySQL is also running.

From a remote computer, I can successfully ping the server

```
ping 129.169.66.149
64 bytes from 129.169.66.149: icmp_seq=48 ttl=63 time=1.010 ms
```

But when I use Telnet:

```
TELNET 129.169.66.149
Trying 129.169.66.149...
telnet: connect to address 129.169.66.149: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Can anyone advise? Is this a firewall issue?

(1) - https://superuser.com/questions/826896/access-wordpress-mysql-database-remotely

Comment: You need to let MySQL listen on all interfaces, meaning that the bind address of mysqld should be `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks @N.B. I tried that before. No change

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First try to check TCP connection issue, using netcat and telnet : on the mysql server, stop mysqld (to release port 3306) and run netcat on listen mode :

```
nc -l -p 3306
```

Now, netcat is listening port 3306 (like mysqld does when it's running) and will show what happen on that port (incoming connections, what's in the wire...).

On your remote computer (mysql client), try to connect to the mysql server host :

```
telnet 129.169.66.149 3306
```

or :

```
nc 129.169.66.149 3306
```

If this is not working, this is not a mysql server configuration issue but a network issue, and you must check your router firewall rules.

Otherwise, your problem comes from mysql server settings. Check your mysql configuration file for `bind-address`, and remove them to make mysqld accept clients from any IP address.

Comment: Thank you! It did not work and so it must be a network issue. I work in a University with significant network protection. I think I need to go and speak to the network manager...

Comment: It was indeed a network issue. My University blocks access to the port MySQL uses

Answer (score 0):

The 3306 port on the 129.169.66.149 server is closed you'll have to open this port
Use this reference as a guide http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-open-ports/

Comment: Thanks @Arlind. I found that the port was indeed open. I believe there is a firewall issue

Comment: @LearningSlowly is the server Windows or Linux?

Comment: haha cool okay so if the problem is in the firewall use this reference to open(allow the outside world to use them) the ports you need https://support.apple.com/en-is/HT201642